# silverlight 3 navigation page not availble in VS as item to add

Tags: visual-studio-2008, silverlight, silverlight-3.0, navigation

I've recently upgraded my computer from Vista Home Premium 64-bit to Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.  I've re-installed VS 2008 web express, and re-installed all the silver light sdk's, tools, etc.

But now when I want to add a Silverlight Navigation Page, it is not avialble to me in the list of items that can be added.  The navigation dll is installed, as my project existed before the OS upgrade.  The program still runs just fine as is, but I want to add another navigation page item to the project, and I'm stumped for how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: +1 I've seen this on one my machines as well, I can't think what has caused it.

Comment: I've been able to work around it, but it would be nice to have a real fix.  I just add a usercontrol and change the root xaml tag from usercontrol to navigation:Page and make sure I've copied all the correct stuff by copying the attributes from another page.

You also have to change the class to inherit from Page.

Answer (score 1):

aparently I installed the silverlight 2 tools after installing the silverlight 3 tools.  Amazingly, while the silverlight 3 dlls were not removed (and therefore continued to work), all the item types for silverlight 3 were removed from Visual Studio.

After a couple weeks I re-downloaded the silverlight 3 install and viola... all the items have returned.